# PhoneGap Cordova Error

Tags: cordova

I recently tried to connect to a client api and was not able to produce a response. the client server responds via google chrome, so i know the internet connection is ok. apparently, when i migrated from apache cordova 2.1 to the latest version of adobe phone gap (cordova 2.2) this past Sunday, i incurred a new security model, that does not permit http requests for assets outside the ipa file.

I know the code works just fine in cordova 2.1, because i tested it a week ago. Any insights, references or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `ExternalHosts` property in `Phonegap.plist`.

If your host does not exist, try adding it or put `*` if you want to allow all outgoing connexions.